# How to host a Laravel 4 project on a domain name?

Tags: php, laravel, web-hosting

I think the question is pretty clear. I'm done with my first project with Laravel 4 and need to host it on a domain. But when I copy and paste the whole Laravel directory (app,public, vendor, etc) and visit the website it shows me the root directory of the project while I need it to show the view which is defined for the home route.

Comment: This is a server configuration issue. You need to point the web root at the `public` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your virtual host needs to point towards the `/public/index.php` file which will bootstrap the framework. If you visit your domain, add `/public` onto the end.